# Avoid that subdomain gets redirected because of WWW canonicalization

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, subdomain, url

I added this URL cnonicalization to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now my subdomain shop.example.com is redirecting to www.example.com. How can I make shop.example.com work again without removing the URL canonicalization?

I use Amazon Web Services.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My edit introduced a typo (*cnonicalization* → *canonicalization*).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to canonicalize `example.com` (only) into `www.example.com` then you should be able to replace this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
```

...with this...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
```

Comment: I Did that, but still redirecting all subdomains, if i type shop.example.com will redirect to www.example.com/shop